# Modifying a function from onclick to onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am very new to javascript and .net fremework. Please help me with this issue. 
Here is the small snippet of my code, and I am displaying a table onclick, but I want it to display on page load.

I have tired window.onload, Placed the code in  tag, placed it in $(documen).ready() but none of them are working, can someone please let me know what are to be modified in order to display the table on page load instead of onclick?

Here is my code snippet:

```
<tr id='group11' class="group1" rel="<%# Eval("RowCount") %>">
    <td colspan="6" class="description first">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleCategory('#group11',<%# Eval("RowCount") %>);" class="control collapse">[-]</a> 
        <a href="javascript:CallDialog('<%# Eval("SummaryMessage") %>');" style= "background-color:yellow">RI [<font size="2"> <i> <%# Eval("LastRI")%> </i> </font>]
        </a>                                                       
    </td>
```

Thank you

Comment: Show us how you tried to handle the onLoad event.

Comment: and where is the table you want to show?

Comment: what does `toggleCategory()` do? Assuming that's what shows the table you want you need to call that function with valid arguments

Comment: This is how I have handled the onload window.onload=function(){
toggleCategory('#group1-RI',<%# Eval("RowCount") %>);
};

Comment: So what happens? Are errors thrown? Does source sent to browser look as expected ?

Comment: Please update the code sample in your question instead of writing it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the usual pattern if you want to wait till the DOM elements are ready is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init(){
  $('myElement').text('Do Stuff with the page')
}
```

---

As an aside: I consider it an antipattern to template your scripts, as you're doing with `onclick="toggleCategory('#group11',<%# Eval("RowCount") %>);`

My preferred solution would be to always execute the same script for all requests.

In your case you might place one element on the page for each item and use that instead of the templated rowCount:

```
function toggleCategory(id, count){
  ...
};
var count = $('#group11 .myItem').length
toggleCategory('#group11', count)
```

Or instead you could pass data from the .NET server to the javascript by adding it to the DOM:

```
<body data-group11count="<%# Eval("RowCount") %>">
  ...
</body>

function toggleCategory(id, count){
  ...
};
var count = $('body').data('group11count');
count = Number(count);
toggleCategory('#group11', count)
```